# Which of these mongodb queries is more efficient? for loop vs deleteMany

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For a mongodb collection with 30+ million documents is it better to:

1: Query multiple times like this:

```
for (const _id of array) {

await Schema.deleteOne({ _id: _id })

}
```

2: One query using `$in`:

```
await Schema.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: array } })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a for loop needs multiple conections to DataBase is a better way use `deleteMany`.

Into [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#db.collection.deleteOne) from `deleteOne` it says:

> To delete multiple documents, see db.collection.deleteMany()

Also, for small databases, a `for` loop may have a not bad performance but with large amount of data this is not a good idea because you are calling your DB multiple times. And also using `await` it stops the execution so this is not efficient.